# Server side validation for Rewards ads in website

Tags: admob, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager, rewardedvideoad, reward-system

I'm website developer and have developed an application which I'm planning to deploy after integrating with Rewards ads in next month. However i did not find any platform which supports server side verification of the rewards video. Does anyone used rewards video ads for website with server verification and whats the platform ?

I see google admanager has the server side validation for the android but no details on the website. Explorer other platforms but they do not have any serverside validation.